# ParserError from `import type { User }` for Svelte app

Tags: tailwind-css, svelte, rollup, parse-error

I'm running into the following `ParseError: Unexpected token` error when trying to start up a Svelte application via the `npm run dev` command:

```
$ npm run dev 

> svelte-app@1.0.0 dev
> rollup -c -w

rollup v3.22.0
bundles src/main.js → public/build/bundle.js...
[!] (plugin svelte) ParseError: Unexpected token
src/App.svelte
4:     import { supabase } from "$lib/db";
5:     import Auth from "$lib/Auth.svelte";
6:     import type { User } from "@supabase/supabase-js";
                   ^
7:     import Home from "$lib/Home.svelte";
```

Here is the `package.json` file that I was using:

```
 {
  "name": "svelte-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "dev": "rollup -c -w",
    "start": "sirv public --no-clear"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^24.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-terser": "^0.4.0",
    "@tsconfig/svelte": "^4.0.1",
    "concurrently": "^8.0.1",
    "rollup": "^3.15.0",
    "rollup-plugin-css-only": "^4.3.0",
    "rollup-plugin-livereload": "^2.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-svelte": "^7.1.2",
    "svelte": "^3.59.1",
    "svelte-check": "^3.3.2",
    "svelte-hcaptcha": "^0.1.1",
    "svelte-preprocess": "^5.0.3",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
    "tslib": "^2.5.2",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4",
    "vite": "^4.3.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.22.0",
    "sirv-cli": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

Please note that I've already found the root cause of the issue and resolved this error.

I will post the answer below in case it also helps anyone else who's running into a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using `rollup` to build the application when I should have been using `tailwindcss`.

The fix was to change the `scripts` commands in the `package.json` file to reflect the need to use `tailwindcss` as shown below:

```
// Package.json file
...
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run dev:css\" \"vite\"",
    "dev:css": "tailwindcss -w -i ./src/tailwind.css -o src/assets/app.css",
    "build": "npm run build:css && vite build",
    "build:css": "tailwindcss -m -i ./src/tailwind.css -o src/app.css",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "check": "svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json"
  },
...
```